# Solve $x^a+x=b$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a general solution for the titular equation?

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I'm not sure how to go about searching for math equations.

Comment: Is $a$ a positive integer?

Comment: Yes, $a$ is a positive integer.

Comment: [How to search this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site#:~:text=Search%20for%20two%20formulas%20at%20the%20same%20time%3A,exactspecifier%20for%20symbols%3A%20OR%20content%3A%24sinleft%28omega%20exact%20t%20right%29%24).

Comment: Is $b$ an integer? Anyway, we have a polynomial equation $x^a+x-b=0$, which we can only solve numerically in general, for $a\ge 5$, see Galois theory.

Comment: $b$ does not have to be an integer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you, I'll check that out!

Comment: @Hau You're welcome!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yup, that answers it for me. Didn't know about Galois theory, but now I do. Thank you!